# Re-indexing repository loop - not Maven

Tags: eclipse, repository

My Eclipse is continuing crashing a running a loop that saying re-indexing repository [myusername] I think it is because of github but I have unchecked everything that could be causing the problem in eclipse preferences under Maven and GitHub. Can someone please help, my computer keeps heating up and crashing. Thanks

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110037/eclipse-hangs-on-re-indexing-fully-repository-username

Answer (score 12):

**First alternative: Git only**

Disable the Refresh settings under Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git.

If that works, you will have to manually refresh either the workspace or the repository (in the Git perspective) after changes to the index or the working tree.

**Second alternative: Eclipse global**

Try disabling both "Refresh..." checkboxes under Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace. That will disable Eclipse to receive notifications from the operating system, when files on disk change by processes outside eclipse.

However, if that solves your issue, you will then have to use <kbd>F5</kbd> (Refresh) on parts  of your workspace resources manually, if an external process (like Maven, Git, ...) modifies files in your workspace.

Comment: Disabling auto-refresh is an extremely unsatisfying answer.  It's like saying your foot hurts so lop off your leg. I have found that sometimes this happens when the output files are being flagged as changed (often by eGit) so every file that gets compiled and written out causes a re-index.  Try making sure your output directory is in your .gitignore so it doesn't cause a re-indexing.

Comment: @Starkii I'm aware of that. In absence of any other alternative answer this still seems the best option up to now. You should probably make an answer out of your egit comment part, as new answers in comments don't get much attention.