# Eclipse hangs on "Re-indexing (fully) repository {username}"

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Eclipse hangs on "Re-indexing (fully) repository /home/{username}". It eventually crashes with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded".

Why does Eclipse try to index the home directory?

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse Git triggers the indexing when the home directory is a git repository (i.e. contains a ".git" folder).

A workaround is to remove  /home/{username}/.git

```
rm -rf /home/username/.git
```

References:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413687
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393332

Comment: Note that the bug is fixed in the newest version of EGit (3.0.3), which is included in Eclipse 4.3.1 (Kepler SR1). In case you upgraded from an older version of EGit, make sure the repository for your home directory is removed from the *Git Repositories* view.

Comment: It worked for me, but i recommend you to be careful before to proceed with the deletion because when i delete the repository my project which is versioned in a svn server was deleted also. It seems that eclipse (STS) versioned my project in the git repo also.