# eclipse: "re-indexing repository workspace" or "Computing Git status for repository workspace"

Tags: eclipse, git, cpu-usage, egit, jgit

I am using eclipse Juno, and yesterday I noticed my computer was getting very hot.  I checked the CPU usage to see it was at 100%.  Eclipse was the culprit, busy "re-indexing repository workspace".  When after half an hour it hadn't finished and my machine was nearly melting, I searched and found these similar problems:

[Re-indexing repository loop - not Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313851)

[Eclipse hangs on "Re-indexing (fully) repository {username}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110037/eclipse-hangs-on-re-indexing-fully-repository-username)

Thing is I'm not using git.  And by the sounds of things I don't want to since it's going to eat all my CPU.  I removed ~/git, deleted a project I have which uses git, checked for any files under ~/.git, removed egit and jgit from eclipse plugins, and it's still happening.

I can stop the process each time, but now it seems unable to build the workspace.

So I decided to upgrade to Kepler, and now I have a similar problem with a different message:

"Computing Git status for repository workspace"

Again it's eating 100% of my CPU and threatening to set fire to my desk.

And I don't even have any open git projects.

How do I stop this stupid thing?  Every time I stop the process, but if I then try to clean rebuild or open a project, it starts up again.

Answer (score 11):

This was an old bug in EGit where it automatically found the `.git` in your home directory and then scanned all the files in the home directory. It has been fixed in newer versions of EGit.

But you may still have the repository configured, even after you upgraded. Do the following:

1. Open the *Git Repositories* view
2. Find the repository that causes the problem
3. In the context menu, select *Remove Repository from View*

Then restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this is my [solution](https://stites.io/2015/09/27/eclipse-hanging-git-status.html)

**Ubuntu 16.04**

```
rm -r workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/*/org.eclipse.egit.core
rm -r workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/*/.indexes/properties.index
```